# react-navigation: Invariant Violation on navigating in push notification using Expo.addListener

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-navigation, expo

When my application receives a push notification, it should navigate to the appropriate screen using a routeName param in the notification data.

This was working until I abstracted our navigation following the NavigationService pattern described in [react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html), and fleshed out more in a react-navigation issue [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1439#issuecomment-303661539).

The problem I'm running into is [from react-navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/d746a587b09676c9ac85d64298340fd5cd0df7e4/src/createNavigationContainer.js#L314): **Invariant Violation: should be set in constructor if stateful**

To resolve this, I've tried moving around the `addListener` call. I've tried the App `componentDidMount`, the AppWithNavigation ref callback (this seems like a bad idea), and the `setContent` method of NavigationService.

I've tried variations of the listener that use NavigationService, and that use `NavigationActions.navigate` directly with `store.dispatch` in App.

My theory is that the navigation container is changing, but navigation works fine except for when the app is closed and a notification comes in. I've even had it working with the app open and in that case it did move to the right screen.

What am I missing here?

**Listener looks like this:**

```
Notifications.addListener(({data}: {data: NotificationType}) => {
  const {routeName, params} = data;
  NavigationService.navigate({
    routeName,
    params,
  });
});
```

**NavigationService.js:**

```
import {StackActions, NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';
import type {NavigationParams, NavigationRoute} from 'react-navigation';

import {LOGOUT} from '../redux/auth';

let _container; // eslint-disable-line

function setContainer(container: Object) {
  _container = container;
}

function reset(routeName: NavigationRoute, params?: NavigationParams) {
  _container.dispatch(
    StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({
          routeName,
          params,
        }),
      ],
    }),
  );
}

function navigate(routeName: string, params?: NavigationParams) {
  _container.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    }),
  );
}

function goBack(options) {
  _container.dispatch(NavigationActions.back(options));
}

function getCurrentRoute(): NavigationRoute | null {
  if (!_container || !_container.state.nav) {
    return null;
  }

  return _container.state.nav.routes[_container.state.nav.index] || null;
}

export function logOut() {
  _container.dispatch({type: LOGOUT});
  reset('Welcome');
}

export default {
  setContainer,
  navigate,
  reset,
  goBack,
  logOut,
};
```

**Part of Navigators.js**

```
class AppWithNavigationState extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {/* Fix for white icons on white status bar bug on iOS */}
        {!isAndroid && <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />}
        <RootStack
          persistenceKey="NavigationState-2"
          ref={navigatorRef => NavigatorService.setContainer(navigatorRef)}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default AppWithNavigationState;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution I ended up with. Not ideal and will look to upgrade to react-navigation 3 as soon as possible. I'm using `renderLoadingExperimental` to render SplashScreen while loading. I can't get a notification when it's done loading, so I added an `onUnmount` to my SplashScreen and I handle registration there.

```
class AppWithNavigationState extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <RootStack
          persistenceKey="NavigationState-2"
          ref={navigatorRef => NavigationService.setContainer(navigatorRef)}
          renderLoadingExperimental={() => (
            <SplashScreen
              source="RootStack"
              onUnmount={() => {
                Notifications.addListener(({data}) => {
                  NavigationService.navigate(data.routeName, data.params);
                  if (Platform.OS === 'android')
                    Notifications.dismissAllNotificationsAsync();
                });
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default AppWithNavigationState;
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. My setup is very similar to yours, the problem was that I was doing navigation in a saga as a side effect before the app navigator was done booting. Check if you are using `persistenceKey`, if so the previous state gets hydrated asynchronously which was the cause of my problem.
I had a callback `navigationReady` in my main navigator that was on`componentDidMount`, but I think I'm gonna have to move it down to the actual screen to avoid the problem. Currently I couldn't find a proper way to subscribe to the action `Navigation / INIT` dispatched by the container after is done restoring everything.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty similar to my issue- side effects before done booting. I got around it by adding an `onUnmount` to my Splashscreen that was waiting for startup to complete. Will post the code...